# How to insert numpy asanyarray value to asanyarray?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, insert, shapes

I have some problems in numpy array code.

I am coding a program to take a frame while photographing with a camera.
I want to save the image values ​​that are fetched for each frame in a list or numpy array, and then I want to take all the pictures and save them all at once.

However, if I try to save it in an array, it will still fail.
Ah, Image's size is 640*480 and fps is 30.

This is Windows 10, pyrealsense, numpy, python 3.6 , cv2 and realsense camera D415.

1. Example code

   ```
   color = []<br>
   color_image = frame.get_color_frame()<br>
   color_array = np.asanyarray(color_image.get_data())<br>
   color.append(color_array)<br>
   ```

If I put this code in it, I will get a few frames, and after 15 frames, the camera frame keeps getting the same frame.

2. Example code

   ```
   test = np.zeros((480,640,3))<br>
   color_image = frame.get_color_frame()<br>
   color_array = np.asanyarray(color_image.get_data())<br>
   np.insert(test, frame_count, color_array)<br>
   ```

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (480,640,3) into shape (480)... why..? :(

In case of 1, different frames must be stored after 15th frame.
In the case of 2, insert the value into the array well. There is no example that should be like this.

Comment: For case 1, after you append to the list `color`, check for frame count and then convert to array: `if num_frames == 15: color_frames = np.array(color, dtype=np.uint8)`

Comment: You don't want to use `np.insert`.  It isn't like list append.  Don't try `np.append` either.  Trying to grow an array iteratively is slow and prone to all kinds of errors.  Appending to a list, and turning that into an array at the end is better.